# SmartyCompilerException error during testlink installation

Tags: testlink

i followed step by step the installation of testink with wamp server.
everything was fine except the last step, when i open the link:
http://localhost/testlink-1.9.14/login.php

i got this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template &quot;C:\wamp\www\testlink-1.9.14\gui\templates\login.tpl&quot; on line 23 &quot;{if $tlCfg-&amp;gt;demoMode}{$labels.demo_usage}{/if}&quot; unknown tag &quot;private_print_expression&quot;' in C:\wamp\www\testlink-1.9.14\third_party\smarty3\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 665
( ! ) SmartyCompilerException: Syntax Error in template &quot;C:\wamp\www\testlink-1.9.14\gui\templates\login.tpl&quot; on line 23 &quot;{if $tlCfg-&amp;gt;demoMode}{$labels.demo_usage}{/if}&quot; unknown tag &quot;private_print_expression&quot; in C:\wamp\www\testlink-1.9.14\third_party\smarty3\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 665
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  303984  {main}( )   ..\login.php:0
2   0.1015  8857432 renderLoginScreen( )    ..\login.php:75
3   0.1034  8972560 Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->display( )    ..\login.php:230
4   0.1034  8976768 Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch( )  ..\smarty_internal_templatebase.php:374
5   0.1047  9006248 Smarty_Internal_Template->compileTemplateSource( )  ..\smarty_internal_templatebase.php:155
```

Can you help me please, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change the persmission of the gui and third_party folder

```
chmod -R 777 gui/

chmod -R 777 third_party/
```